# Handling SQL Time data type

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have a mySQL database with a 'TIME' data type for my `RenewalTime` field.

The input for this field is in military time and looks like `03:00:00'

I am trying to set a class up to receive the table information. All of the fields work except my time field.

So far, this is what i have for the variable in my class

```
[DisplayName("Renewal Time")]
        public DateTime RenewalTime { get; set; }
```

This doesnt work though. At the time the table is being filled i receive this error `Error parsing column 13 (RenewalTime=03:00:00 - Object)`

ideas?

Comment: Its `MySQL` so I am not sure, but shouldn't it be [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `DateTime`

Answer (score 5):

You need `TimeSpan`, Not `DateTime` for `Time` field

```
[DisplayName("Renewal Time")]
public TimeSpan RenewalTime { get; set; }
```